# Reading excel file in R : arguments imply differing number of rows

Tags: r, excel

I am trying to read an Excel file in R. I have manually made a file like this.

A  B  C

1  2  3

3  1  2

I am using this code that is giving me the error

> arguments imply differing number of rows : 2, 1, 0

```
my_data <- read.xlsx('file.xlsx', sheetName='data', startRow=1,colNames=FALSE,
           rowNames=TRUE,rows=NULL,cols=NULL,na.strings="NA")
```

Can you please guide me what am I doing wrong ?

Comment: This works `my_data <- xlsx::read.xlsx("file.xlsx", sheetName="data", startRow=1)`?

Comment: Please, mark answered if it's solved. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The error occurs when you pass `rows = NULL` or `cols = NULL` through `read.xlsx()`. `read.xlsx` passes arguments to `data.frame()`, and you're dropping both columns and rows by defining them as `NULL`.

As here:

```
> myData <- read.xlsx("file.xlsx", sheetName='data', startRow = 1, colNames = F, rowNames = T, rows = NULL, cols = NULL, na.strings = "NA")
Error in data.frame(res, ...) : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 2, 1, 0
```

We can fix this by removing `rows = NULL` and `cols = NULL`:

```
> myData <- read.xlsx("file.xlsx", sheetName='data', startRow = 1, colNames = F, rowNames = T, na.strings = "NA")
> myData
  A B C colNames rowNames na.strings
1 1 2 3    FALSE     TRUE         NA
2 3 1 2    FALSE     TRUE         NA
```

Note: `colNames`, `rowNames`, and `na.strings` are interpreted as variables to be passed into the resulting `data.frame()`, as they are not arguments for `read.xlsx()`.

As a proof of what's going on, you can see here:

```
> data.frame(1:3,1:3, rows = NULL)
Error in data.frame(1:3, 1:3, rows = NULL) : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 3, 0
```

as compared to:

```
> data.frame(1:3,1:3)
  X1.3 X1.3.1
1    1      1
2    2      2
3    3      3
```

TL;DR? Remove `rows = NULL` and `cols = NULL` from your call to `read.xlsx()`.

Answer (score 0):

See [this](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/xlsx/versions/0.5.7/topics/read.xlsx) and [this](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/data.frame.html) and pay attention to `xlsx::read.xlsx` arguments.
Then, consider this code

```
#use header instead of colNames
#use row.names instead of rowNames
#no na.strings argument in xlsx::read.xlsx (but openxlsx::read.xlsx use na.strings)
my_data <- xlsx::read.xlsx("file.xlsx", sheetName = "data", startRow = 1,
                           header = TRUE, row.names = NULL)
```